# Parse/Swift не правильно загружаются данные в ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, parse.com

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста при парсенге с TableViewCell? не правильно загружаются данные во  ViewController.Что еще нужно добавить?Вот мой код.

```
 import UIKit
  import Parse

        class DetailSportViewController: UIViewController {

            @IBOutlet weak var imageDetail: UIImageView!
            @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
            @IBOutlet weak var titleDetail: UILabel!
            @IBOutlet weak var prognozDetail: UILabel!

            var soccers : Soccer?

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                textView.font = textView.font?.withSize(10)
                detailObject()
            }

            override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
                super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
                // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
            }

            override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
                super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            }

            @IBOutlet weak var outClose: UIButton! {
                didSet {
                    outClose.layer.cornerRadius = 20
                    outClose.layer.masksToBounds = true
                }
            }

            @IBAction func actionClose(_ sender: Any) {
                dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
            }

            func detailObject() {
            let query = PFQuery(className: "soccer")
            query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects: [PFObject]?, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    for object in objects! {
                        let imageDetail = object["detailImageS"] as? PFFile
                        imageDetail?.getDataInBackground(block: { (data, error) -> Void in
                            if error == nil {
                                if let image = data {
                                    self.imageDetail.image = UIImage(data: image)
                                    self.prognozDetail.text = object["detailPrognozS"] as? String
                                    self.textView.text = object["detailTextS"] as? String
                                    self.titleDetail.text = object["detailTitleS"] as? String
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Какой парсинг с TableViewCell? О чем Вы? P.S. советую Вам сделать рефактор detailObject(), иначе там получается pyramid of doom. И читать такой код очень сложно.

Comment: Прочитал то я внимательно, в Вашем вопросе вообще не понятно о чем речь. И что значит в перемешку? И как Вы передаете данные из ячейки в контроллер?

Comment: Значит так у меня вот класс "футбол".Я указал название матча и дату(Это у меня в tableViewCell) сделал ему кастомное открытие.У меня это View Controller и мой код опубликовал.Например я написал описание про матч и название и присвоил ему картинку.И сделал 4 матча.ТАк вот оно все идет в разброс.

Comment: В таблице или в контроллере?

Comment: Ну так покажите что у вас записывается и что вы вместо этого ожидаете. Я вообще не понял вопроса.

Comment: во ViewControllere. Описание, название ...Например матч Россия-Словения, а к нему присвоился от Турции -Хорватии описание и картинка.

Comment: Мне кажется, что дело в этом - dispatch_sync. Ну то есть данные синхронно закидывать надо. А так он что видит (что готово) то и кидает. Без очереди.

Comment: Кикие данные передает ваша ячейка? Вы уверены, что она передает верные данные?

Comment: Уточните: вот вы получили массив объектов objects: [PFObject], далее идете по циклу  for object in objects и устанавливаете значения лейблов, так получается если у вас в массиве их много, то будут показаны данные только последнего объекта. Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: Ну тогда вот и ответ, Вы в цикле переписываете данные и получаете всегда данные последнего в массиве

Comment: ну а как это исправить, не подскажите пример.Я вот сижу листаю вопросы на английском сайте вопросы, и смотрю не у одного меня.как сделать правильный цикл

Comment: Вам надо по какому то признаку выйти из цикла. Скажем проверить что ид матча который в ячейке равен ид матча в массиве. Псевдокод в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо найти в массиве нужный объект и выйти из цикла.

```
for object in objects {
  if object.id == objectID {
     // Тут сетите нужные данные
     break
  }
}
```

Comment: Я думаю если у меня такая причина.Вообще убрать цикл.Зачем он тут.

Comment: Ну это уже зависит от вашего решения =)

Comment: Виталий подскажите как парсить правильно ViewController без цикла, я вот не нашел ни одну статью?

Comment: По идее Вы должны передать нужные данные сразу в контроллер. Как вариант может быть можно запросить не все объекты, а только объект с нужным ид например, я сам не работал с Parse, не знаю его API.